# How do I stream audio from a respeaker 2-mic hat in a raspberry pi with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999595/what-steps-are-needed-to-stream-rtsp-from-ffmpeg) to stream audio from a mic in my raspberry pi.

```
ignacio@pi-satellite-bigbedroom:~ $ ffmpeg -re -f pulse -ac 1 -i plughw:CARD=seeed2micvoicec,DEV=0 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://192.168.86.151:8554/live.stream
ffmpeg version 4.3.6-0+deb11u1+rpt5 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt5 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-sand --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
plughw:CARD=seeed2micvoicec,DEV=0: No such process
```

I believe this shows the cards I have:

```
ignacio@pi-satellite-bigbedroom:~ $ pactl list sources
Source #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_audio.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_audio.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "bcm2835 Headphones"
        alsa.long_card_name = "bcm2835 Headphones"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_bcm2835"
        device.bus_path = "platform-bcm2835_audio"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/soc/3f00b840.mailbox/bcm2835_audio/sound/card0"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #1
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.platform-soc_sound.stereo-fallback.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 12
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.platform-soc_sound.stereo-fallback
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 2000000 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "seeed-2mic-voicecard"
        alsa.long_card_name = "seeed-2mic-voicecard"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_simple_card"
        device.bus_path = "platform-soc:sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/soc/soc:sound/sound/card2"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "2"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #2
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.platform-soc_sound.stereo-fallback
    Description: Built-in Audio Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 12
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 32845 /  50% / -18.00 dB,   front-right: 32845 /  50% / -18.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 20724 /  32% / -30.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 688 usec, configured 10000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0"
        alsa.id = "bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "seeed-2mic-voicecard"
        alsa.long_card_name = "seeed-2mic-voicecard"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_simple_card"
        device.bus_path = "platform-soc:sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/soc/soc:sound/sound/card2"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hw:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "stereo-fallback"
        device.profile.description = "Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Ports:
        analog-input: Analog Input (type: Analog, priority: 10000, availability unknown)
    Active Port: analog-input
    Formats:
        pcm
```

I want to use the mic from the seeed-2mic-voicecard.

Thanks for the help